# Why is my result variable not being changed?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

So I am trying to solve N-Queens problem, and when I console.log(result) inside the solve function I am getting the correct output. but when I return the result array in the end, it seems like the result array has not been mutated at all, as I get [[-, -, -,-], [-,-,-,-]]

```
function solveNQueens(n) {
  let result = [];
  let buffer = Array(n).fill('-');
  
  function solve(bufferIndexRow) {
    if (bufferIndexRow === n) {
      result.push(buffer);
      return console.log('FOUND ONE SOLUTION'); // Finished last row, filled queens array
    }

    for (let column = 0; column < n; column++) {
      buffer[bufferIndexRow] = column;
      if (isValid(bufferIndexRow, column)) {
        solve(bufferIndexRow + 1);
      }
      buffer[bufferIndexRow] = '-'
    }
  }
  
 function isValid(row, col) {
    for(let i = 0;  i< row; i++) {
      if(buffer[i] == col || Math.abs(i - row) == Math.abs(buffer[i]- col))
          return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  solve(0);
  return result;
}

console.log(solveNQueens(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass in buffer to solve so that it can push the updated buffer to result